# Nice general way to sort nulls to the bottom, regardless?

Tags: java, design-patterns, comparator

I'm writing some custom Comparators, and I'd like them to push null items to the bottom of the list, regardless of whether I'm sorting ascending or descending.  What's a good strategy or pattern for approaching this?

Offhand:

- Simply write separate ascending and
  descending comparators, sharing code
  where possible
- Delegate null handling to another
  class, either by throwing an NPE or
  by calling it explicitly
- Include an ascending flag and put
  conditional logic in it to navigate
  around the nulls
- Wrap regular comparators in a
  null-handling class

Any other strategies?  I'd like to hear about any experiences with different approaches, and any pitfalls for the various strategies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last option appeals to me a lot. Comparators are really great to chain together. In particular you may well want to write a `ReverseComparator` as well as a `NullWrappingComparator`.

---

EDIT: You don't have to write this yourself. If you look at the [Ordering](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.java) class in the [Google Collections Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) you'll find this and all kinds of other goodies :)

---

EDIT: Going into more detail to show what I mean about `ReverseComparator`...

One word of warning - in the implementation of a `ReverseComparator`, reverse the order of the arguments instead of negating the result, as otherwise `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is "reversed" to itself.

So this implementation is wrong (assuming `original` is the comparator to reverse):

```
public int compare(T x, T y)
{
    return -original.compare(x, y);
}
```

but this is right:

```
public int compare(T x, T y)
{
    return original.compare(y, x);
}
```

The reason is that we always want to reverse the comparison, but if `original.compare(x, y)` returns `int.MIN_VALUE`, then the bad comparer will *also* return `int.MIN_VALUE`, which is incorrect. This is due to the funny property that `int.MIN_VALUE == -int.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: I agree with all of your answer except about negating the result of a compare; I'd be fairly unhappy if I found out that a Comparator was implementing integer comparison using subtraction, since that method has so many pitfalls.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because of the reference to Google Collections' Ordering class - existing proven code is the best solution.  Also for the warning about Integer.MIN_VALUE.  But I greatly appreciate @dfa's code, below, and wish I could accept both answers.

Answer (score 12):

I agree with Jon Skeet (it's so easy :).  I tried to implement a very simple [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern):

```
class NullComparators {

    static <T> Comparator<T> atEnd(final Comparator<T> comparator) {
        return new Comparator<T>() {

            public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
                if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {
                    return 0;
                }

                if (o1 == null) {
                    return 1;
                }

                if (o2 == null) {
                    return -1;
                }

                return comparator.compare(o1, o2);
            }
        };
    }

    static <T> Comparator<T> atBeginning(final Comparator<T> comparator) {
        return Collections.reverseOrder(atEnd(comparator));
    }
}
```

given a Comparator:

```
Comparator<String> wrapMe = new Comparator<String>() {
      public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
          return o1.compareTo(o2);
      }
};
```

and some test data:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(null, "aaa", null, "bbb", "ccc", null);
```

you can sort with nulls at end:

```
Collections.sort(strings, NullComparators.atEnd(wrapMe));
```

```
[aaa, bbb, ccc, null, null, null]
```

or at beginning:

```
Collections.sort(strings, NullComparators.atBeginning(wrapMe));
```

```
[null, null, null, ccc, bbb, aaa]
```

Comment: Very nice!  Thank you.  Is there a reason for not returning 0 if both arguments are null?  I know that null behavior is not quite like non-null behavior, and that saying two nulls are equal is questionable - but is it less questionable to say that one exceeds the other?

Comment: @Carl: Exactly the point I just made to your post :) A Comparator *should* return 0 or throw an exception when passed two nulls, otherwise it's disobeying the interface contract.

Answer (score 6):

Following up on dfa's answer - what I want is that the nulls sort at the end without affecting the order of the non-nulls.  So I want something more along the lines of this:

```
public class NullComparatorsTest extends TestCase {
    Comparator<String>  forward = new Comparator<String>() {
                                    public int compare(String a, String b) {
                                        return a.compareTo(b);
                                    }
                                };

    public void testIt() throws Exception {
        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(null, "aaa", null, "bbb", "ccc", null);
        Collections.sort(strings, NullComparators.atEnd(forward));
        assertEquals("[aaa, bbb, ccc, null, null, null]", strings.toString());
        Collections.sort(strings, NullComparators.atBeginning(forward));
        assertEquals("[null, null, null, aaa, bbb, ccc]", strings.toString());
    }
}

public class NullComparators {
    public static <T> Comparator<T> atEnd(final Comparator<T> comparator) {
        return new Comparator<T>() {
            public int compare(T a, T b) {
                if (a == null && b == null)
                    return 0;
                if (a == null)
                    return 1;
                if (b == null)
                    return -1;
                return comparator.compare(a, b);
            }
        };
    }

    public static <T> Comparator<T> atBeginning(final Comparator<T> comparator) {
        return new Comparator<T>() {
            public int compare(T a, T b) {
                if (a == null && b == null)
                    return 0;
                if (a == null)
                    return -1;
                if (b == null)
                    return 1;
                return comparator.compare(a, b);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Full credit to dfa, though - this is just a minor modification of his work.

Comment: One problem: you don't return 0 when comparing two nulls.

Answer (score 5):

In Java 8, you can use the [`Comparator.nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-) and [`Comparator.nullsFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) static methods to have more null-friendly comparators. Suppose you have a `Fruit` class like the following:

```
public class Fruit {
    private final String name;
    private final Integer size;

    // Constructor and Getters
}
```

If you want to sort a bunch of fruits by their size and put the `null`s at the end:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = asList(null, new Fruit("Orange", 25), new Fruit("Kiwi", 5));
```

You can simply write:

```
Collections.sort(fruits, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparingInt(Fruit::getSize)));
```

And the result would be:

```
[Fruit{name='Kiwi', size=5}, Fruit{name='Orange', size=25}, null]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always use [`NullComparator`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/comparators/NullComparator.html) from commons-collections. It's been around longer than Google Collections.