# Find the earliest date among 3 dates

Tags: java, date, min, date-comparison

I have three dates in Java: a, b, c.  Any or all of these dates may be null.  What's the most efficient way of determining the earliest date among a,b,c, without having a massive if-else block? I would want a the actual date that is earliest among a,b,c. Any date is better than a null date.

Comment: and what have you tried that is not so efficient?

Comment: Do you need to know which date is the earliest (i.e. tie it back to the variable), or just the value?

Comment: You could convert each Date to its millisecond representation and use a compound Math.min to determine the smallest value

Comment: Is null greater or smaller than any date?

Comment: I would want a the actual date that is earliest among a,b,c.  Any date is better than a null date.

Comment: See the similar Question, [Nice general way to sort nulls to the bottom, regardless?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1261934/642706).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There's no getting around null checking, but with some refactoring you can make it painless.

Create a method that safely compares two dates:

```
/**
 * Safely compare two dates, null being considered "greater" than a Date
 * @return the earliest of the two
 */
public static Date least(Date a, Date b) {
    return a == null ? b : (b == null ? a : (a.before(b) ? a : b));
}
```

then combine calls to that:

```
Date earliest = least(least(a, b), c);
```

---

Actually, you can make this a generic method for any `Comparable`:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T least(T a, T b) {
    return a == null ? b : (b == null ? a : (a.compareTo(b) < 0 ? a : b));
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Java 8+ oneliner. To make it safe, null check is added. Pass any number of dates.

```
public static Date min(Date... dates) {
    return Arrays.stream(dates).filter(Objects::nonNull).min(Date::compareTo).orElse(null);
}
```

**Not null safe**, but much shorter:

```
public static Date min(Date... dates) {
    return Collections.min(Arrays.asList(dates));
}
```

**Not null safe** without a new method:

```
Collections.min(Arrays.asList(date1, date2));
```

Comment: If you are using Java or higher you should not use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Depending on exact requirements use `Instant` or another class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Even on Java 6 or 7 you may consider the same using [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Comment: * using Java **8** or higher

Comment: @OleV.V. I prefer to use `Date` in most cases, because there is no issues to use it in DTO with Spring MVC (`spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=true`), no timezone problems between JavaScript (Angular, React, etc) and Java using REST.  In JS just use `new Date(timeFromServer)` without any parsers. You don't ever think about a timezone when `Date` comes from frontend and goes with Hibernate (also `Date`) to database and vice versa. Also it perfectly works with Swagger (OpenAPI). It's very well supported by all new and old frameworks. 
New time API is perfect for time math.

Comment: `Date` has caused innumerable time zone errors over the years. Hibernate 5 supports java.time just fine. [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) too. Tastes differ.

Answer (score 11):

When Apache Commons is available, you might use [`ObjectUtils.min`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#min-T...-):

```java
Date earliest = ObjectUtils.min(a, b, c);
```

Comment: Shortest solution +1

Answer (score 7):

Well, 'efficient' has some different meanings, but I don't think there will be an efficiency problem with comparing three dates. In fact, it's really cheap. You can try this approach:

```
SortedSet<Date> dates = new TreeSet<Date>();
dates.add(date1);
dates.add(date2);
// ...
dates.add(dateN);
Date earliest = dates.first();
```

Or, maybe more elegant:

```
for (Date date : someDates) {
   if (date != null) {
      dates.add(date);
   }
}
Date earliest = dates.first();
```

Comment: but it's sorts all elements, and redundant in task of finding min

Comment: The former crashes with a `NullPointerException` when a date is null. The latter crashes with a `NoSuchElementException` if all three are. The answer is also outdated since it uses the problematic and outmoded `Date` class.

Answer (score 6):

Some Java 8 methods using streams. The first will filter nulls before comparing, the second will put them at the end of the list.

```
Date minDate = Arrays.asList(date1, date2, etc).stream()
     .filter(Objects::nonNull).min(Date::compareTo).get()
```

or

```
Date minDate = Arrays.asList(date1, date2, etc).stream()
    .sorted((a, b) -> {
        //some kind of custom sort.
        if(a == null && b == null) return 0;
        if(a == null) return 1;
        if(b == null) return -1;
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }).findFirst().get()
```

Comment: Won’t the second one fail with a `NoSuchElementException` if all the dates are `null`? PS Don’t use `Date`.

Answer (score 6):

### `java.time.LocalDate`

The `java.util.Date` & `java.sql.Date` classes were supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

For Java 8 and later, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) for a date-only value.

To get the earliest of a list of dates:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public static LocalDate earliestDate(LocalDate... dates) {
    return
        Arrays
        .stream(dates)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .min(LocalDate::compareTo)
        .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: My answer specifically covers Java 8 LocalDate which none of the others does.

Comment: I hadn’t noticed. Very well, I changed  my down-vote to an up-vote, and removed my Comment. I suggest you add some prose explaining your use of `LocalDate`, the benefits, and how your Answer is different and better.

Answer (score 3):

### Arrays.asList(), Collections.min() and a null-safe comparator

```
    LocalDate a = LocalDate.of(2025, Month.JANUARY, 6);
    LocalDate b = null;
    LocalDate c = LocalDate.of(2023, Month.NOVEMBER, 22);

    List<LocalDate> dates = Arrays.asList(a, b, c);
    LocalDate earliest = 
        Collections.min(
            dates,
            Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())
        );

    System.out.println("Earliest date: " + earliest);
```

I consider this both clear and short and simple, also compared to the stream solutions in a couple of other answers. Output is:

> Earliest date: 2023-11-22

If all three dates happen to be `null`, the output is:

> Earliest date: null

Often we prefer `List.of()` over `Arrays.asList()` when passing each element; but since `List.of()` does not accepts nulls, we can’t use it here.

Do use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for a date. The `Date` class used in some of the answers had severe design problems and has been outdated the last 10 years (and counting).

The idea can obviously be used with any class that implements `Comparable` and any number of objects of that class.

### Documentation links

- [`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))
- [`Collections.min(Collection, Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection,java.util.Comparator))
- [`Comparator.nullsLast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast(java.util.Comparator))
- [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder())
- [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html)

Comment: Simple and elegant solution! Comparator.nullsLast() fits perfectly with the requirements. I liked this solution over the previous ones on this page. Thanks for this quality contribution!

Answer (score 2):

Use the java Date object http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

You can use the before() and after() functions of these objects then

Answer (score 2):

using before and after :

```
  /**
     * find Min Dates
     * @param date1
     * @param date2
     * @return
     */
    public static Date minDate(Date date1, Date date2) {
        // if date1 before date2 then return date1 else return date2
        return date1.before(date2) ? date1 : date2;
    }
     /**
     * find Max Dates
     * @param date1
     * @param date2
     * @return
     */
    public static Date maxDate(Date date1, Date date2) {
        // if date1 after date2 then return date1 else return date2
        return date1.after(date2) ? date1 : date2;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using stream:

```
Date min = Stream.of(date1, date2, etc)
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  .min(Date::compareTo)
  .orElse(null);
```

If your array does not contain NULL values you can use `Ordering`

```
Ordering.natural().min(date1, date2, etc);
```

Comment: Which `Ordering` type is that?? Neither my IDE nor [my documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/index-files/index-15.html) knows of it. PS Don’t use `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [java.util.Collections.min(collection)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection)):

> Returns:
>       the minimum element of the given collection, according to the natural ordering of its elements.

```
public static Date getEarliestDate(List<Date> dates) {

    if (dates == null || dates.isEmpty())
        return null;

    dates.removeIf(Objects::isNull);

    return dates.isEmpty() ? null : Collections.min(dates);
}
```

Comment: Since the OP had three dates `a`, `b` and `c`, the natural thing to pass to your method is `Arrays.asList(a, b, c)`. When I do that, I get an `UnsupportedOperationException` from the call to `removeIf()` if one of the dates is indeed `null`. PS Don’t use `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're also using kotlin and if entries are not null, it becomes as simple as `minOf(a, b, c)`. If they can be null, `listOfNotNull(a, b, c).minOrNull()`.
For a collection, it's `dates.filterNotNull().minOrNull()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
date1.compareTo(anotherDate)
```

Returns:

the value 0 if the argument Date is equal to this Date; a value less than 0 if this Date is before the Date argument; and a value greater than 0 if this Date is after the Date argument.

Throws:

```
NullPointerException -
```

if anotherDate is null.

Answer (score 0):

just another version as an idea and for fun

```
new Date(Math.min(a != null ? a.getTime() : Long.MAX_VALUE
, Math.min(b != null ? b.getTime() : Long.MAX_VALUE
, c != null ? c.getTime() : Long.MAX_VALUE)))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List.of(date1, date2)
                .stream()
                .min(Date::compareTo)
                .get();
```

It is simple solution which I wanted to share that could be used in a private method when you are sure all dates are not null.

Comment: sorry for my fault, really did not read a question.
However, it is simple solution, which I wanted to share that could be used in private method when you sure all dates are not null