# Compare a Date with three or more Date(s) in Java 8?

Tags: java, date, java-8

With the java.time API it is possible to compare *two* dates using the following syntax:

```
date1.before(date2);
```

or

```
date2.after(date1);
```

This however becomes very verbose when comparing 3 or more dates.
Is there a way of comparing a Date with multiple others, to see if the one provided is before/after all the other ones?

Comment: If you don't see it in the javadocs, my guess is "no".  You'd have to write your own.

Comment: Since `Date` implements `Comparable<Date>`: `date.before(Collections.min(Arrays.asList(date1, date2, date3))` and `date.after(Collections.max(Arrays.asList(date1, date2, date3))`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820951/find-the-earliest-date-among-3-dates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you're trying to do here is to compare the date to just *one* of your "3 or more" dates: you just have to work out which one that is, and then compare two dates.

Since `Date` implements `Comparable<Date>`, you can use `Collections.min` and `Collections.max` to find the earliest and latest of them:

```
Date earliest = Collections.min(Arrays.asList(date1, date2, date3));
Date latest   = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(date1, date2, date3));
```

Then:

```
boolean beforeEarliest = date.before(earliest);
boolean afterLatest    = date.after(latest);
```

etc.

Comment: Just a matter of taste, but I personally like the compact variant as in your comment better...

Comment: @Aconcagua sure, I'd use that too. I just wrote it out "long-hand" so I could name the variables to make it more clear what I was doing.

Comment: @AndyTurner I suggest you post this fine answer on [the original](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15820951/642706) of this duplicate Question.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is about `Java 8`, here’s a “Java 8ish” solution:

```
boolean beforeEarliest = Stream.of(date1, date2, date3).allMatch(date::isBefore);
boolean afterLatest    = !beforeEarliest &&
                         Stream.of(date1, date2, date3).allMatch(date::isAfter);
```

This is not only a “Java 8 style” solution, compared to [Andy Turner’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37594215/2711488), it performs lesser comparisons.

For either of the two tests, to find the minimum, resp. maximum of `n` elements, you need `n-1` comparisons, then the found element is compared to `date`, thus, always having a total of `n` comparisons. In contrast, this stream based solution will compare *at most* `n` elements with the reference `date`, having at most `n` comparisons. Since this stream based solution is short-circuiting, i.e. stopping at the first non-matching element, the total number of comparisons is lower, unless all of them match, in which case the first comparison of the other test will fail.

You can change the `Collections.min`/`Collections.max` solution to also skip the second test if the first one succeeded, but the worst case still is `2*n` comparisons whereas the worst case of the Stream based solution is `n+1` comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you put all in a collection, maybe it helps: 
Collections.max(dates);
Collections.min(dates);